# Can I change Earth Engine's pyramid scheme for a dataset?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'd like to change Earth Engines pyramid scheme for a particular dataset from the mean() of pixels to the max() of pixels.

Is there any way to do this?

I suspect not.

My use case is that I'm making a multiband image from a number of different sources, and want to get the max of pixels in one of the images (which is the one with the finest resolution) when I stratifiedSample the multiband image at a particular scale.

I suppose another option would be to somehow downscale all the other images when adding them to the multiband image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `reduceResolution` for that sort of thing.

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/resample#reduce-resolution

Comment: related question: is it possible to know the pyramiding policy of an asset? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/436788/how-to-determine-pyramiding-policy According to that answer, Java users cannot know, which can bring very bad surprises hard to trace back? Thanks!